# Convert from sql to jpql with clause IN

Tags: sql, jpql

I have this request in SQL that I have converted in  JPQL

```
===SQL===
 SELECT * FROM ELEVE WHERE ELEVE.AGE IN ('7','8','5','6', '12' ) 

===JPQL===

SELECT E FROM ELEVE E  WHERE E.AGE IN ('7','8','5','6', '12' )
```

But It doesn't work could someone explain me what I missed

Comment: and when you say it doesn't work , what does it mean? what's the error message you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing * or the column names after your select , it can be `E.*` or just `*` or if you want to specify specific column names it should be like `E.columnanme` :

```
===SQL===
 SELECT * FROM ELEVE WHERE ELEVE.AGE IN ('7','8','5','6', '12' ) 

===JPQL===

SELECT E.*  FROM ELEVE E  WHERE E.AGE IN ('7','8','5','6', '12' )
```

Comment: I don't need an * in jpql

Comment: in your second query you are using Select E , while E is the name of the table but not a column, so you should either use * from name the columns

Comment: Do you want me to add * to get all the columns or to get one column ? In fact I fought that E matched all the columns in jpql that is why I have done it like that

Comment: not me but sql wants you to put column names or * after select

Comment: Ok thank you but do you know jpql is  it the right way to convert my sql to jpql ?

Comment: I think you should decide that based on your needs,